# .change() Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of elements with class `xyz`. The requirement is a user needs to input one number in them only. I then need to concat them. For example, their meter would read `1` `2` `0` `0`.

I have below.

```
$('.xyz').change(function () {
     console.log($(this));
     arrayNums.length = 0;
     var thisRead = parseInt(CombinedNumber(arrayNums), 10);
     var lastRead = parseInt($('.abcd').html(), 10);
     if ((thisRead - lastRead) <= 1) {
         $('#idthing').html("Your Last reading compared to this reading is " + (thisRead - lastRead) + " KWH <br>Are you SURE you want to submit this Reading?");
         $('#idthing').attr('style' , 'color: red !important');
     }
     else { $('#idthing').text(thisRead - lastRead + ' KWH');}
});

function CombinedNumber(arrayNums) {
        combined = "";
        $('.xyz').each(function (index) {
            arrayNums.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.each(arrayNums, function (index, value) {
            combined += value;
        });
        console.log(combined);
        return combined
```

This works the first time, if the user clicks off of the area, before hitting the submit button, but they might hit the submit button first.
Additionally, it ceases to do the calculation after the first time it happens!

I am trying to get a responsive calculation each time someone enters a number. Here is the DOM portion.

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li>
       <input class="xyz">
   </li>
   <li>
       <input class="xyz">
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting `input` having class `xyz` on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `change` as `change` handler will be invoked only when `focus` of the element is lost.

```js
var arrayNums = [];
$('.xyz').on('input', function() {
  console.log($(this));
  arrayNums.length = 0;
  var thisRead = parseInt(CombinedNumber(arrayNums), 10);
  var lastRead = parseInt($('.abcd').html(), 10);
  if ((thisRead - lastRead) <= 1) {
    $('#idthing').html("Your Last reading compared to this reading is " + (thisRead - lastRead) + " KWH <br>Are you SURE you want to submit this Reading?");
    $('#idthing').attr('style', 'color: red !important');
  } else {
    $('#idthing').text(thisRead - lastRead + ' KWH');
  }
});

function CombinedNumber(arrayNums) {
  combined = "";
  $('.xyz').each(function(index) {
    arrayNums.push($(this).val());
  });
  $.each(arrayNums, function(index, value) {
    combined += value;
  });
  console.log(combined);
  return combined;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class="xyz">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="xyz">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Input did it! Thank you. That is a lot more responsive than change! I would recommend using this all the time when you need to trigger something based on inputs.

Comment: Wait, same issue. If I go back to a previously entered input, and change it, the text does not update.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **jQuery** Instead of $

```
      jQuery('.xyz').change(function () {
         console.log($(this));
         arrayNums.length = 0;
         var thisRead = parseInt(CombinedNumber(arrayNums), 10);
         var lastRead = parseInt($('.abcd').html(), 10);
         if ((thisRead - lastRead) <= 1) {
             $('#idthing').html("Your Last reading compared to this reading is " + (thisRead - lastRead) + " KWH <br>Are you SURE you want to submit this Reading?");
             $('#idthing').attr('style' , 'color: red !important');
         }
         else { $('#idthing').text(thisRead - lastRead + ' KWH'); }
      });

      function CombinedNumber(arrayNums) {
         combined = "";
         $('.xyz').each(function (index) {
             arrayNums.push($(this).val());
         });
         $.each(arrayNums, function (index, value) {
             combined += value;
         });
         console.log(combined);
         return combined;
     }
```

Comment: Any specific reason ?

Comment: what's your jQuery version you are using ? Because it happens to me also and I replaced $ to jQuery.

Comment: Do little google about `$` vs `jQuery`.. And I am not the OP by the way :)

Comment: if you are using more than one javascript library there can be conflicts if you just use the $. using jQuery will avoid those.

Comment: All right.. How does that make a difference in the scenario presented by OP ?

Comment: Sorry bro but what's the meaning of OP ? And these is my experience while working,  at first load of DOM $ works properly but sometimes once the DOM load on page  $ gets conflicts. To overcome that I used jQuery instead of $

Comment: @Anandjain certainly put the reason in your answer next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating inputs having class `.xyz` dynamically (May be on click event of button) then below code would be work here. try to replace `$('.xyz').change(function ()` with `$(document).on('change','.xyz',function ()`

```
$(document).on('change','.xyz',function () {
     console.log($(this));
     arrayNums.length = 0;
     var thisRead = parseInt(CombinedNumber(arrayNums), 10);
     var lastRead = parseInt($('.abcd').html(), 10);
     if ((thisRead - lastRead) <= 1) {
         $('#idthing').html("Your Last reading compared to this reading is " + (thisRead - lastRead) + " KWH <br>Are you SURE you want to submit this Reading?");
         $('#idthing').attr('style' , 'color: red !important');
     }
     else { $('#idthing').text(thisRead - lastRead + ' KWH');}
});
```